# How to log outgoing HttpClient request body to Application Insights dependencies table?

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-application-insights

I have a .Net core Web App API which accept request from front-end and then send HTTP POST request to Azure search to get search results.

I just use the build-in application insights logging log basic info in request and dependencies sources with zero logging code.

Now I want to extend the default Application Insights dependencies table to add the request body to Azure search.

What is the easiest way with minimum code?

Answer (score 0):

As per your requirement, you can try the code below:

```
public class RequestBodyInitializer : ITelemetryInitializer
{
    readonly IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor;

public RequestBodyInitializer(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
{
    this.httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
}

public void Initialize(ITelemetry telemetry)
{
    if (telemetry is RequestTelemetry requestTelemetry)
    {
        if ((httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Method == HttpMethods.Post ||
             httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Method == HttpMethods.Put) &&
            httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Body.CanRead)
        {
            const string jsonBody = "JsonBody";

            if (requestTelemetry.Properties.ContainsKey(jsonBody))
            {
                return;
            }

            //Allows re-usage of the stream
            httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.EnableRewind();

            var stream = new StreamReader(httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Body);
            var body = stream.ReadToEnd();

            //Reset the stream so data is not lost
            httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Body.Position = 0;
            requestTelemetry.Properties.Add(jsonBody, body);
        }
    }
}
```

and add this to the Startup > ConfigureServices

```
services.AddSingleton<ITelemetryInitializer, RequestBodyInitializer>();
```

Comment: Thanks. But what I want is to log the outgoing request body. Basically, front-end call my API, and my API use HTTP client call another API, I want to log the HTTP request body sent from http client.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code to capture request body of outbound dependencies.

```
public class DependencyEnhanceInitializer : ITelemetryInitializer
{    
    public void Initialize(ITelemetry telemetry)
    {
        if (telemetry is DependencyTelemetry dependencyTelemetry)
        {
           if (dependencyTelemetry.Properties != null && dependencyTelemetry.TryGetOperationDetail("HttpRequest", out var requestObject))
            {
                var request = requestObject as HttpRequestMessage;

                try
                {
                    if (request?.Content != null)
                    {
                        var result = request?.Content?.ReadAsStringAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
                        if (result != null)
                        {
                            dependencyTelemetry.Properties.Add("RequestBody", result);
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    //Handle exception as appropriate
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then add this as singleton in your startup

```
services.AddSingleton<ITelemetryInitializer, DependencyEnhanceInitializer>();
```

Similarly, you can use TryGetOperationDetail with "HttpResponse" as well.

> **Note:** We are using GetAwaiter().GetResult() for reading the body, therefore the application might take a hit in performance under heavy loads.

Comment: I tried to find a way to make it async call instead of blocking wait https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/issues/2679 but could not find a way. Ideally, I would keep this disabled in production systems with high load and enable it on-demand.